# how to reset index pandas dataframe after dropna() pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm not sure how to reset index after `dropna()`. I have

```py
df_all = df_all.dropna()
df_all.reset_index(drop=True)
```

but after running my code, row index skips steps. For example, it becomes 0,1,2,4,...

Comment: [`dropna` now supports `ignore_index=True` to automatically reset the index, so you can avoid the follow up `reset_index` call.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The code you've posted already does what you want, but does not do it "in place."  Try adding `inplace=True` to `reset_index()` or else reassigning the result to `df_all`.  Note that you can also use `inplace=True` with `dropna()`, so:

```
df_all.dropna(inplace=True)
df_all.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Does it all in place. Or,

```
df_all = df_all.dropna()
df_all = df_all.reset_index(drop=True)
```

to reassign `df_all`.

Answer (score 4):

#### pandas >= 2.0: [`dropna` now supports `ignore_index=True`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna)

pandas >= 2.0

```
df
     A    B   C
0  1.0  5.0   9
1  2.0  NaN  10
2  NaN  7.0  11
3  4.0  8.0  12

df.dropna() # by default, dropna does not reset the index

     A    B   C
0  1.0  5.0   9
3  4.0  8.0  12

df.dropna(ignore_index=True) # now resets the index

     A    B   C
0  1.0  5.0   9
1  4.0  8.0  12
```

This allows you to skip the follow up `reset_index` call.

Implemented in [GH31725](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31725)

---

for older pandas versions (< 2.0)

```
df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)

     A    B   C
0  1.0  5.0   9
1  4.0  8.0  12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain methods and write it as a one-liner:

```py
df = df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

You can reset the index to default using `set_axis()` as well.

```py
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df.set_axis(range(len(df)), inplace=True)
```

`set_axis()` is especially useful, if you want to reset the index to something other than the default because as long as the lengths match, you can change the index to literally anything with it. For example, you can change it to `first row`, `second row` etc.

```py
df = df.dropna()
df = df.set_axis(['first row', 'second row'])
```

[image: res]