# After dropping pandas DataFrame rows, How to still locate a row by the same index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-preprocessing

When you delete a row from a DataFrame, the subsequent rows will shift up with their indexes.. but if you try to locate a row by its index.. you get a different row than expected because the index values have been reset to reflect the new positions of the rows in the DataFrame...
and I want to still be able to locate any of the rows by their original index

for example:
this is before and after I dropped 0 and 2 rows

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

and this is what I get when I locate the row with index 1:

[image]

how can I still get the row with index 1 ???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to reset index pandas dataframe after dropna() pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40755680/how-to-reset-index-pandas-dataframe-after-dropna-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: no, unfortunately. I dont want to reset the indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.loc` to index the dataframe by the index name:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([4,3,2,1])
df.drop([0,2], inplace=True)

# To return a Series
df.loc[1,:]

# Or to return a DataFrame
df.loc[[1],:]
```